# Android: tag rotation in imageview cutting image inside listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

i'm new in android development and i'm trying rotating an image view inside a listview. I have the follow xml for the custom cell:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/borderImageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/photoReceiverWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/photoReceiverHeight"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:rotation="-10"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

When it display, it cut a peace of the image. The view is not calculating the size for the rotation.

I don't want to create a new bitmap because the cost is too high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

This is an image view property, so place it within the image view rather than the relative layout. I am not sure if adjustViewBounds works on a fixed size ImageView.

You could change the width and height to `wrap_content` and use a `maxHeight` or `minHeight` property to define some additional bounding rules.

The scale type should also probably be `centerInside`, but play with these to see what suits.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, maybe i need to redraw the bitmap.